# Update/sync all repo to the specific commit in submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have repo structured in the following way:

```
|- project/
|  |- tools/
|  |- toolchain/
|     |- linux/
|     |- windows/
|  |- code/
|  |- shared/
|
```

Where `tools`, `code` and `shared` are submodules. Also `/toolchain/linux` and `/toolchain/windows` are submodules too.

The problem is I want to switch in `code` for a specific commit. To build my code I need to sync all other submodules with that commit (let's say toolchain for linux was updated and I can't build old code with latest toolchain). How to do it in git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the corresponding commit in the superproject `project` and check it out; it then will recursively check out all submodules to their stored commits.

*The following code requires Unix tools (`sh`, `xargs`, `awk`).*

This pipeline

```bash
git rev-list @ code/ |
xargs -I @ sh -c "echo -n '@ '; git rev-parse @:code"
```

prints a list of pairs of commits IDs: a commit from the superproject where the submodule was changed, and the commit of the submodule. Filter it by the required commit in the submodule and print the commit from the `project`:

```bash
git rev-list @ code/ |
xargs -I @ sh -c "echo -n '@ '; git rev-parse @:code" |
awk '$2=="$commitID_from_code" {print $1}'
```

Now let's automate checkout:

```bash
git rev-list @ code/ |
xargs -I @ sh -c "echo -n '@ '; git rev-parse @:code" |
awk '$2=="$commitID_from_code" {print $1}' |
xargs -r git checkout --recurse-submodules
```

Or `git switch --detach --recurse-submodules` instead of `git checkout`.

Will do nothing if the pipeline didn't find the specified commit.